# panic: testing: Verbose called before Init

Tags: go, testing, benchmarking, channel

Trying to run
https://github.com/adonovan/gopl.io/blob/master/ch8/cake/cake_test.go

but got

```sh
panic: testing: Verbose called before Init

goroutine 1 [running]:
testing.Verbose(...)
  /usr/lib/go-1.17/src/testing/testing.go:453
.../cake_test.init()
```

It says the error comes from `cake_test.init()`, yet the `cake_test.go` file doesn't contain `init()`:

```
$ grep init cake_test.go | wc
      0       0       0
```

What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The error is telling you that the [initialization of a package level variable](https://github.com/adonovan/gopl.io/blob/1ae3ec64947b7a5331b186f1b1138fc98c0f1c06/ch8/cake/cake_test.go#L14) called testing.Verbose() before [testing.Init()](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#Init) was called.

Comment: you should not call testing.Verbose() outside Test functions. Consider create a helper makeDefault() that returns a new structure each time needed. The issue is the init is called inside the testing package itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this specific case, adding Init() function did the trick.

```
var defaults cake.Shop

func Init() {
    defaults = cake.Shop{
        Verbose:      testing.Verbose(),
        Cakes:        20,
        BakeTime:     10 * time.Millisecond,
        NumIcers:     1,
        IceTime:      10 * time.Millisecond,
        InscribeTime: 10 * time.Millisecond,
    }
}
```

Comment: Bravo! Thanks and welcome aboard with my +25!

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the testing package itself has a init to process test flags and you are callind Verbose to create a global variable

https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18:src/testing/testing.go;l=548

To avoid this you can:

1. Use a ponter to function to capture testing.Verbose and use inside functions, after all initializations ( Verbose will be type `func() bool`) but I think this is complex
2. Add a helper that creates a new default on each test with a safe call to testing.Verbose
3. Create a constructor (instead a test helper) that fill with the most common options and you can set the value of Verbose on each test
4. Create a two constructors, a second one that receive the value of Verbose

Also, Consider create a method `Debug` with same signature of Println, to call fmt.Println if Verbose is true

If you have a constructor, you can create a second field: Logger, with is a ponter to function with same signature as Println and you initialize with fmt.Println and in the tests you can set as t.Log to have a better experience

Of course perhaps some suggestions are more advanced than others, feel free to play a little bit and choose the best ones